# Powershell Adding Multiple Stylized Tables in Word Document Mixed With Text

Tags: powershell, ms-word, comobject, word-table

Essentially I am making a list of invoices as a bill, it will look like this (in word through powershell, note that the word file doesn't pre-emptively exists, i create a new one and start adding to it):
[image]

The problem is that I only know how to do the following:

```
$word = New-Object -comobject word.application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $word.Selection
$Selection.Style="Title"
$Selection.Font.Bold = 1
$Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
$Selection.TypeText("Expected Billing")
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.Style="No Spacing"
$Selection.Font.Bold = 0
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$doc.SaveAs([ref]$savepath) 
$doc.Close() 
$word.quit()
```

Adding text is easy but when it comes to adding tables, I cant get it right.
As you can see:

- The addresses table is 2 columns and 3 rows but no borders
- the amount of invoice tables isn't fixed
- the first column is aligned left
- Quantity and Amount are aligned right (since they will be numbers)
- Supplier and Dealer are centered

Actually the numbered tables aren't supposed to have borders either but I left them so you visually see.
Then of course the total calculated amount which I can do. But notice it comes after the tables so I want tables appending and want to know how to append after them.
Can someone help me out? I don't know the coding for this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after doing more research I figured it out.
I will post the code

```
    $Range = $Selection.Range
    $Table = $Selection.Tables.add($Selection.Range,2,5)
    $Table.cell(1,1).range.text = "Item Code"
    $Table.cell(2,1).range.text = "Description"

    $Table.cell(1,2).range.text = "Quantity"
    $Table.cell(1,3).range.text = "Amount"
    $Table.cell(1,4).range.text = "SUP"
    $Table.cell(1,5).range.text = "Dealer Code"
    $Selection.EndKey(6) | Out-Null
```

You have to start with the add and make sure you end with End Key(6)

To edit width or font style:

```
   $Table.cell(1,1).Width = 222.2 
   $Table.cell(1,1).range.Font.bold = 1
```